# Effect of \vphantom{E} in tabular*?

Tags: tables, spacing

I am relatively new to LaTeX, and I am confused on what exactly `\vphantom{E}` does in this case, and why it has this impact.

I have a table with 2 columns, and the items on each row are horizontally separated with a dots. I believe I have made it so the table is 6.5in wide, with the items left and right justified.

Here is a picture of the table, which looks as expected. However, I would like to reduce the whitespace after the last row without using `\vspace`. I tried removing the `\vphantom` command, and the table does not fill up the entire 6.5in anymore.

[image]

```
\newcommand{\award}[2]
{
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{#1 \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep} #2}\\
}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular*}{6.5in}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \award{Text text text text text text text}{2019}
        \award{Text text text text text text text Text text text text text text text}{2018-19}
        \award{Text text text text text text text Text text text text text text text}{2018}
        \vphantom{E}
    \end{tabular*}
\end{center}
```

Removing the `\vphantom{E}` results in this:

[image]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document  beginnng with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`  which we can test.

Comment: @Zarko I apologize for not providing a MWE. There are a lot of things in the document I am still learning about and I couldn't clean it up to leave only this part and still produce the outputs pictured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\award}[2]{#1 \dotfill  #2\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{5.5in}}
        \award{Text text text text text text text}{2019}
        \award{Text text text text text text text Text text text text text text text}{2018-19}
        \award{Text text text text text text text Text text text text text text text}{2018}
     \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For correct working of `\dotfill` you need to have well defined (multi column) cell width, what is not in your table. It become if you add a fake line, for example with  `~ & ~` (`~` is invisible character) or with simply `&` or with `\vphantom{E}` (by which you define vertical space of this table row in the first column and left second column undefined, what is wrong), which make table width equal to prescribed one.

I use `\dotfill` since your document preamble is unknown and `\cftdotfill` is in my document example undefined.

The same result you can obtain with use of `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\award}[2]{#1 \dotfill #2\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{5.5in}
        \award{Text text text text text text text}{2019}
        \award{Text text text text text text text Text text text text text text text}{2018-19}
        \award{Text text text text text text text Text text text text text text text}{2018}
     \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```